# vaadin BeanFieldGroup binding issue with combobox

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm not sure if I understand correctly BeanFieldGroup but I hope it should bind values from fields(UI components) to my custom beans (eg POJOs).

Here I have my POJO.

```
public class JobConfigDTO {

    @Max(50)
    private String format;

    @Max(50)
    private String template;

    @Max(50)
    private String channel;
}
```

With this code I'm attempting to bind my POJO to checkboxes.

```
private void test(){

    JobConfigDTO jobConfigDTO = new JobConfigDTO();
    ComboBox comboChannel = createEditFormCombobox("Channel", "CHANNEL");
    ComboBox comboFormat = createEditFormCombobox("Format", "FORMAT");
    ComboBox comboTemplate = createEditFormCombobox("Template", "TEMPLATE");

    BeanFieldGroup<JobConfigDTO> binder = new BeanFieldGroup<>(JobConfigDTO.class);
    binder.setItemDataSource(jobConfigDTO);
    binder.setBuffered(false);
    binder.bind(comboChannel, "channel");

    binder.bind(comboChannel, "channel");
    binder.bind(comboFormat, "format");
    binder.bind(comboTemplate, "template");

    Button btnSave = new Button("Add");
    btnSave.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent event) {
            try {
                log.debug("jobconfigdto {}", jobConfigDTO);
                binder.setBuffered(true);
                log.debug("jobconfigdto {}", jobConfigDTO);
                binder.commit();
                binder.setBuffered(false);
            } catch (FieldGroup.CommitException e) {
                log.error("Unable to save job config", e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

When I set values for comboboxes in form and click add button pojo JobConfigDTO is not filled.

Am I missing something or BeanFieldGroup has another usage? I would like to bind values from checkboxes to my pojo class and validate them at the end.

Comment: Problem solved. I was using another POJOs (Config) in my Checkboxes so framework was not able to populate my JobConfigDTO field values with this POJOs(Config). When I changed the checkboxes entries to string. Everything works.

Comment: You can mark it as solved, so it won't appear in unanswered section.